# Why can not I cancel a wrong review?

Tags: feature-request

Today, while busy with something else, I voted to close a question of a new member.

Two or 3 minutes later, I landed on the same question and I regretted my review because it was rather in-topic question and a good one.

I think this is the third time I did such a mistake.

**Q:**

Why is not there a feature to cancel our wrong reviews? That will have a good benefit as moderators and other trusted users will have less erroneous reviews to handle everyday.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Comment: Or the same question I asked myself a few time ago: [Why can't we retract a close vote?](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/1817/32746). Basically: go on the post, click the close link, you will access a special button allowing you to retract your close vote (I guess SE people should definitively make this more intuitive...).

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf Yes, thank you.